# AutoHotKey Run Windows Commands

Tags: windows, command-line, autohotkey

Is there a way to run Windows command line commands in AutoHotKey without just opening a command prompt and sending the key presses?

I want to run commands hidden in the background.  For example

> del C:\Users\Test\Desktop\test.txt

I know there is a delete file command in AutoHotKey but I want to be able to run other command line commands that don't work in AHK.  That was just an example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
run, %comspec% /c del C:\Users\Test\Desktop\test.txt,,hide
```

%comspec% points to cmd.exe
if you need to run as admin, you'll want to look at runas.

Comment: +1 for `,,hide`!

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to use `%ComSpec%` as pointed by [the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1192931/856975). You can use `cmd.exe` and use `/c` which is the command indicator, it will run anything in front of it, inside cmd.

`Run cmd.exe /c del C:\Users\Test\Desktop\test.txt`

Here's how the syntax of it looks like:

`Run, Target, WorkingDir, Options, OutputVarPID`

`RunWait, Target, WorkingDir, Options, OutputVarPID`

If you need for a command to finish and then continue, use `RunWait`. To save the output of a command, for example if you want to save your WAN IP address in your clipboard, you can pipe the output with the `clip` command.

```
RunWait, cmd.exe /c nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | clip
```

If you need a one line answer, you can use the `find` command to remove unwanted lines:

```
RunWait, cmd.exe /c nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | find /i "address" | find /v "208.67.222.222" | clip
```

You can hide the cmd window from showing up with the option `hide`:

`Run cmd.exe /c del C:\Users\Test\Desktop\test.txt,,hide`

---

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm