# AutoHotKey run cmd with pretyped text, without executing

Tags: windows, command-line, autohotkey

[Existing Q&A's](https://superuser.com/q/1192892/1010638) handle running commands, but I simply wish to open `cmd` with pretyped text, since a part of the command changes with each use.

Fully dummy example, I'd like to launch `cmd` with `del "py" --arg`  pretyped - the `"` is intentional (escape issues with some examples I've seen). Then, I'd manually add `main` to delete `main.py`.

Is it doable? Looking for something other than `Run cmd.exe`, then "wait", then `SendInput`, since `cmd` doesn't launch instantly and the input can go elsewhere.

Comment: I'm keeping the question open to better approaches / minimal functioning code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something close to your last sentence (every time a command prompt launches, it types something in), except for two things, 1) using WinWaitActive to make sure command prompt is open and 2) sometimes sending the input in a loop with a check for WinActive to make sure it is still active (i.e., stop sending if another window steals focus).

This doesn't avoid having text sent elsewhere 100% of the time, but it does work most of the time (in your example I might also split the command into three parts and send each one with a check for WinActive in between, if there were window-focus problems).

The only other option besides SendInput is to send the text to the window by window ID, which I've had less success with for various programs (look at ControlSend).

If there was actually a programmatic way to do what you're asking about though, that would be great (maybe someone else will know).

---

Post Part 2, in response for a minimal coding excerpt...

Part A)

This framework can be used to call a function only the first time a window becomes present. Option 'C' in the setup parameters. You can write your own stripped down version just to wait for a window, but this script will keep track of which windows have appeared already, vs. re-executing if focus shifts and comes back.

https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/84397-winwait-framework-do-something-to-a-window-when-it-appears/

Putting cmd.exe the config section might be something like:

```
ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass ahk_exe i)cmd.exe              C       newCmdWindow(`%WA_ID`%)
```

Note that the script uses [typically non-visible] tabs in the config section between the three sets of text shown above, WinTitle, WindowType and Function

Part B)

`newCmdWindow()` function needs to be defined...

```
newCmdWindow(myID)
{

    strToSend:="REM :: USE " q("POPD") " TO JUMP BACK HERE..." "{Enter}" "pushd C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop" "{Enter}"        ; Init

    ;------------------------------------------------------
    ; Minimize collateral damage if window changes
    ;------------------------------------------------------
    Loop, Parse, % strToSend, %A_Space%    ; Parse on spaces
    {
        Sleep, 10 ; give window time to stabilize / make sure windows title isn't changing / minimize colateral damage if window changes
        If WinActive("ahk_id" myID)
            SendInput % (A_Index > 1) ? A_Space A_LoopField : A_LoopField

    }
}
```

(Original use: This function will jump to a custom folder from any command prompt location, so you can set a 'default' location that always opens, but you can also get back to whatever the location was that the command prompt ran in, by using the `popd` command. For example if you run cmd.exe from an explorer window and specifically want to use a command prompt in that folder, it will navigate to the default folder, but you can get back just by typing `popd`. This different than setting a hard-coded default folder that always opens)

Once you have the window-detection framework in place, just set the function to send whatever you want to send, and it will be sent the first time any new command prompt is activated.

Comment: Thanks, I'd also appreciate if you included a minimal code excerpt (concerning first paragraph)

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not savvy with AHK and don't quite follow. Could you put it in one code block with user(me)-filled parts shown exactly instead of as placeholders? Let's say the command is `del "py" --arg` (`"py"` intentional since there may be escaping problems), and directory be `cmd`'s default if possible, or if it must be specified let's say it's `C:\Users`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Hotstring](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotstrings.htm)

```
#IfWinActive Command Prompt ahk_exe cmd.exe
:*:---::del "py" --arg{space}
```

Open a cmd prompt, type `---`, your cmd shows up.

Comment: Didn't work for me, also tried pressing Space or Enter